# Объединить 2 одномерных массива в 1 ассоциативный ключ-значение

Tags: php

имеется два массива `keys[]` и `values[]`.
нужно объединить их так, чтобы первый элемент `keys[0]` был ключом первого элемента второго массива, то есть:

```
keys[0] => values[0],
keys[1] => values[1];
```

Как это реализовать?

Comment: А о каком языке программирования идет речь? PHP **или** JavaScript?

Comment: php или js? И причем тут html?

Comment: извиняюсь первый раз на stackoverwlof, вот наворотил, язык php ответ получил ниже, всем спасибо) сильно не пинайте

Comment: @mozomig, если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ на вопрос, отметьте его как "принятый" (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете виду `php`, то не ленитесь заглядывать в документацию. Вам нужна простая функция [array_combine](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php):

```
$newArray = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

Comment: Да вы телепат ;)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev только учусь )) а у вас интернет наверно быстрее т.к. всегда правлю вопрос и на долю секунды опережаете меня ((